# How to change colors on treemap

Tags: r, ggplot2

Anyone know how I can change the colors on my treemap? I'd like to be able to update from the current color scheme.

```
group <- c("China", "India", "United States", "Germany", "Russia",
        "Japan", "South Africa", "South Korea", "Poland", "Australia")
value <- c(4320, 966, 731, 257, 230,
       210, 202, 157, 149, 130)

df <- data.frame(group, value) 
# install.packages("treemapify")
library(treemapify)
# install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(area = value, fill = group, label = value)) +
geom_treemap() +
geom_treemap_text()
# install.packages("treemapify")
library(treemapify)
# install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(area = value, fill = group,
           label = paste(group, value, sep = "\n"))) +
geom_treemap() +
geom_treemap_text(colour = "white",
                place = "centre",
                size = 15) + 
theme(legend.position = "none" )
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a color scale to the `fill` aesthetic to change the palette.

The base plot with default colors

```r
ggplot(df, aes(area = value, fill = group, label = value)) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap_text()
```

[image]

Adding `scale_fill_brewer` to use a pre-defined palette:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(area = value, fill = group,
               label = paste(group, value, sep = "\n"))) +
  geom_treemap() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set3') +
  geom_treemap_text(colour = "white",
                    place = "centre",
                    size = 15) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none" )
```

[image]

There are many ways to adjust plot aesthetics like this, and its worth looking over this [chapter on color scales](https://ggplot2-book.org/scales-colour.html) from the ggplot book.